# How to iterate through lazy iterable in scala? from stanford-tmt

Tags: scala

Scala newbie here,

I'm using stanford's topic modelling toolkit

and it has a lazy iterable of type `LazyIterable[(String, Array[Double])]`

How should i iterate through all the elements in this iterable say `it` to print all these values?

I tried doing this by

```
while(it.hasNext){

System.out.println(it.next())

}
```

Gives an error

```
 error: value next is not a member of scalanlp.collection.LazyIterable[(String, Array[Double])]
```

This is the API source -> iterable_name ->
`InferCVB0DocumentTopicDistributions` in

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/api/edu/stanford/nlp/tmt/stage/package.html

Answer (score 2):

Based on [its source code](https://github.com/MLnick/scalanlp-core/blob/master/data/src/main/scala/scalanlp/collection/LazyIterable.scala), I can see that the `LazyIterable` implements the standard Scala `Iterable` interface, which means you have access to all the standard higher-order functions that all Scala collections implement - such as `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, etc.

The one you will be interested in for printing all the values is `foreach`. So try this (no need for the while-loop):

```
it.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like method invocation problem, just check the source code of [LazyIterable](https://github.com/MLnick/scalanlp-core/blob/master/data/src/main/scala/scalanlp/collection/LazyIterable.scala), look at line 46

```
override def iterator : Iterator[A]
```

when you get an instance of LazyIterable, invoke iterator method, then you can do what you want.

Comment: Lazyiterable is an abstract class, so i cannot create an object to it. How would you suggest i create one and iterate?

Comment: First, LazyIterable is a trait not an abstract class considering the definition 
```trait LazyIterable[+A] extends LazyIterableLike[A,LazyIterable[A]]```. Second, "when you get an instance of LazyIterable"  I mean there must be some methods to return an instance of LazyIterable(could be the instance of its subtype). Since, you mention "i cannot create an object to it", I suggest
you find the concrete subtype of LazyIterable (or companion object of that subtype)and try to create instance with that type. Sorry to let you misunderstand.